# IIS Express keeps running

Tags: visual-studio-2017, iis-express, visual-studio-debugging

I recently upgraded to VS2017 pro, and IIS express continues to run after I stop the debugger in visual studio.

I know this is the reverse of most of these questions (aka how to keep IIS express running), but I can't figure out how to get IIS express to stop when I stop the debugger. I've unchecked the option for "Edit and Continue," but IIS express doesn't stop unless I right click on it in the notification bar and kill it.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: If understood it correctly we need turn "Edit and Continue " on other than off  if we want IIS stop after debugging: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/07/11/enable-edit-and-continue-debugging-option-is-now-on-by-default-for-new-web-applications-in-vs2013-preview/

Comment: @FletchZhou-MSFT I originally thought that as well, and it was enabled by default, yet IIS would not stop. I unchecked it just to test, and it did not change anything. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

"**Edit and Continue**" works with **Web application**:
[image]

[“Enable Edit and Continue” debugging option is now on by default for new web applications](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/07/11/enable-edit-and-continue-debugging-option-is-now-on-by-default-for-new-web-applications-in-vs2013-preview/)

For **WebSite** project, and **there is no** this option.